# Creating an order-slot system with 2 array lists

Tags: java

I need to write a daymanagerr that assigns time slots for orders in a restaurant.

That's the daymanager:

```
public DayManager (LocalDate date, int numberOfTimeSlots, int capacityPerSlot) {
        this.date = date;
        this.capacityPerSlot = capacityPerSlot;
        this.numberOfTimeSlots = numberOfTimeSlots;
```

For each day I can choose the number of available slots and the capacity per slot (so if I choose 3 slots and a capacity of 3 per slot, that's 9 slots in total).

Every customer can state their preferred time slot (here: 0, 1 or 2) with their order.

Here's my class for adding orders:

```
public Optional<Integer> addOrder(Order order, int preferredSlot) {
            int givenSlot = 0, count = 1;
            List<Integer> slots = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> slotsPerSlot = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                if ((slots.size() * slotsPerSlot.size()) <= (numberOfTimeSlots * capacityPerSlot)) {
                    if (slots.contains(preferredSlot) == false) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                        slots.add(preferredSlot);
                        slotsPerSlot.add(count);
                        count++;
                    } else if (slotsPerSlot.size() <= capacityPerSlot) {
                        givenSlot = preferredSlot;
                        slots.add(preferredSlot);
                        slotsPerSlot.add(slotsPerSlot.size() + 1);

                    } else {
                        givenSlot = slots.get(slots.lastIndexOf(count));
                    }
                    return Optional.of(givenSlot);
                }
                return Optional.empty();
            }
```

What I need help with:

With every new order I get, I need to check if there is still capacity left in that customers preferred slot. If there is capacity left, I assign that slot to him. If there is no capacity left in that slot, I assign the slot with the next lowest index (and available capacity). If there is no capacity left for that day, I simply return nothing.

I just can't figure out how to create a slotsPerSlot list for each slot and additionally I don't really know, how I could get the next lowest slot number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Multimap

You could use a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). A [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) is a pairing of key that leads to a value. In a multimap, the value is actually a collection of values rather than a single value.

Imagine, for example, a hierarchy of three time slots where the first and last contain an empty list (no orders yet), while the middle time slot has a list of a single order.

- 2022-01-23T13:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]

  - []
- 2022-01-23T14:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]

  - [Order[id=2d8e5cc2-26ac-474d-a081-2c71207fd6c5, customerName=Basil]]
- 2022-01-23T15:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]

  - []

(Minor detail: The `2d8e5cc2-26ac-474d-a081-2c71207fd6c5` text is a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string representation of a 128-bit [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) value used to identify that particular order.)

### Example code

Here is some example code. This code is incomplete, but will get you going in the right direction.

First, define our `Order` class. We will make it a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), using the new feature in Java 16. You could just as well define a conventional class, but a record is so much briefer. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
package work.basil.example.orders;

import java.util.UUID;

public record Order(UUID id , String customerName)
{
}
```

Define the `DayManager` class.

The constructor is the place to set up your data structure for tracking orders. You were doing that work inside your `addOrder` method which makes no sense.

The goal of the constructor is to populate a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), a `Map` that maintains its keys it a sorted order. We use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) as the concrete implementation of the `NavigableMap` interface.

The keys to our map are [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), a date with time-of-day within the context of a time zone. Each `ZonedDateTime` object is the start of each time slot. I use this approach rather than your mere integer number to identify each slot.

The values of our map are a list of `Order` objects. As we add orders to our tracking system, they land in one of these lists. Each list is tied to a `ZonedDateTime` object as the time slot in our map. The problem with using a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is that the class is meant to be a resizable collection. So our code here manages the size limits, checking the current size to get a count of how many orders are already present in the list. We compare that count to our capacity-per-time-slot number we keep as a member field on `DayManager` class.

- If we are under capacity, we add our order to the list, and return an `Optional` containing the `ZonedDateTime` to identify the time slot.
- If we are at capacity, we need to move on to the next time slot — this I leave as an exercise for the reader.

  - Hint: We have a `ZonedDateTime` in hand, the current key used to access our map. So if we add the `Duration` stored as a member field, we will obtain the next key in our map. Use that key to get the next list of orders. [Lather, rinse, repeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lather%2C_rinse%2C_repeat), until moving past the last time slot of the day.

By the way, in real work, I would look to a third-party library such as [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) or [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) for a fixed-size list class. Better to rely on code that is already written and tested than rely on our size-checking code here.

We pre-populate our map with time slots and empty lists in the constructor. So we have a data structure in place when we begin adding orders.

The `addOrder` method looks for the requested time slot as the key in the map. Doing a `get` on the map returns a `List` of orders for us to inspect.

```java
package work.basil.example.orders;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DayManager
{
    // Member fields.
    final ZoneId zoneId;
    final LocalDate workDate;
    final LocalTime startTime;
    final Duration timeSlice;
    final int numberOfTimeSlots, capacityPerTimeSlot;
    private final NavigableMap < ZonedDateTime, List < Order > > ordersPerTimeSlot;

    // Constructor
    public DayManager ( final ZoneId zoneId , final LocalDate localDate , final LocalTime startTime , final Duration timeSlice , final int numberOfTimeSlots , final int capacityPerSlot )
    {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
        this.workDate = localDate;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.timeSlice = timeSlice;
        this.numberOfTimeSlots = numberOfTimeSlots;
        this.capacityPerTimeSlot = capacityPerSlot;

        this.ordersPerTimeSlot = new TreeMap <>();
        this.populateMap();
    }

    // Subroutine.
    private void populateMap ( )
    {
        ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( this.workDate , this.startTime , this.zoneId );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.numberOfTimeSlots ; i++ )
        {
            Duration d = this.timeSlice.multipliedBy( i );
            ZonedDateTime zdt = start.plus( d );
            List < Order > list = new ArrayList <>( this.capacityPerTimeSlot );
            this.ordersPerTimeSlot.put( zdt , list );
        }
        System.out.println( "this.ordersPerTimeSlot = " + this.ordersPerTimeSlot );
    }

    // Business logic.
    public Optional < ZonedDateTime > addOrder ( final Order order , final ZonedDateTime zdt )
    {
        List < Order > orders = this.ordersPerTimeSlot.get( zdt );
        if ( Objects.isNull( orders ) ) { return Optional.empty(); }
        if ( orders.size() > this.capacityPerTimeSlot )
        {
            String msg = "ERROR - Capacity per time slot exceeded. ";
            System.out.println( msg );
            throw new IllegalStateException( msg );
        } else if ( orders.size() == this.capacityPerTimeSlot )
        {
            String msg = "INFO - This time slot filled.";
            System.out.println( msg );
            throw new IllegalStateException( msg );
        } else if ( orders.size() < this.capacityPerTimeSlot )
        {
            // Room in this time slot to place order.
            orders.add( order );
            return Optional.of( zdt );
        } else
        {
            String msg = "ERROR - Should never reach this point. Error in IF-THEN logic of adding orders.";
            System.out.println( msg );
            throw new IllegalStateException( msg );
        }
    }

    // Debugging
    public String dumpOrders ( )
    {
        return this.ordersPerTimeSlot.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is an `App` class for exercising our `DayManager` & `Order` classes.

```java
package work.basil.example.orders;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" );
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
        DayManager dm = new DayManager( z , ld , LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) , Duration.ofHours( 1 ) , 3 , 3 );

        Order order = new Order( UUID.fromString( "2d8e5cc2-26ac-474d-a081-2c71207fd6c5" ) , "Basil" );
        Optional < ZonedDateTime > optionalTimeSlot = dm.addOrder( order , ZonedDateTime.of( ld , LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) , z ) );

        System.out.println( "order = " + order );
        System.out.println( "optionalTimeSlot.toString() = " + optionalTimeSlot );
        System.out.println( dm.dumpOrders() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
this.ordersPerTimeSlot = {2022-01-23T13:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[], 2022-01-23T14:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[], 2022-01-23T15:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[]}
order = Order[id=2d8e5cc2-26ac-474d-a081-2c71207fd6c5, customerName=Basil]
optionalTimeSlot.toString() = Optional[2022-01-23T14:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]]
{2022-01-23T13:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[], 2022-01-23T14:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[Order[id=2d8e5cc2-26ac-474d-a081-2c71207fd6c5, customerName=Basil]], 2022-01-23T15:00-07:00[America/Edmonton]=[]}
```